# Does animation make page so much slower?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have here any animation on my page: https://tikex-dev.com

[image]

`active` class turn on this:

```
animation: btn-text-anima 1s linear infinite
```

If I turn it off, page laggin almost dismiss. Why is this animation so performace intensive?

```css
.btn-text:not(.btn-video).active:after {
    animation: btn-text-anima 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes btn-text-anima {
    0% {
        right: -30px;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    60% {
        right: -40px;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        right: -45px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick observation, the animation is fast and infinite, that's enough to tell you that it will cause lag

Comment: Is it a way to prevent lagging though keep this animation? Do you know?

Comment: `btn-text-anim` tells me you're using it for buttons and text, presumably in a lot of places, maybe reduce that, otherwise there's no getting around it the easy way, i wonder if triggering hardware acceleration would help, then again this is a whole site and it's not that easy to debug lag by hand

Comment: Could you show us the keyframes associated with that animation? Sometimes it’s possible to get the GPU to take things on.

Comment: btn-text-anima is added

Comment: Do *not* animate right, this is really bad. Try to use transform to achieve your goal instead!

Comment: If you use transform translate the system knows that won’t affect anything else so it should be much less processor intensive.

Comment: @Lux would you show an example? Anyway, why 'right' is so bad? :D

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chaning the `right` attribute in your animation is probably the root cause of the problem. This is because the `right` attribute defines the *position* of the element, on which other positions depend, resulting in a complete redraw.

So you should use `transform`, which will run after the rendering in a post-processing step.

So using something like `transform: translateX(-30px);` instead of `right: -30px` should help you. How this will exactly behave will however depend on other contetn of your page, but this should give you a general idea.